# Suppose $f$ is real-valued function defined on $[1,\infty)$ with $f(1)=1$.Suppose, moreover, that $f$ satisfies...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is real-valued function defined on $[1,\infty)$ with $f(1)=1$.Suppose, moreover, that $f$ satisfies $$f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}$$.
Show that $f(x)\le 1+\pi/4$ for every $x\ge 1$.

My work:
Clearly $f'(x)>0$. So,$f(x)\ge 1$ in the given domain.
Now,I used the inequality,
$f(x)=\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}dx\ge \int \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}dx$
But, I cannot proceed any further. Please help!

Comment: yes, i have got that...from where I get $\pi/4$.But, what next?

Comment: Your integrals need limits ...

Comment: Write $$f(x)-f(1)=\int_1^x {1\over t^2+f^2(t)}\,dt\le\int_1^\infty {1\over  t^2+1}\,dt=\pi/4.$$

Comment: So,you mean it will be less than equal to and not greater than equal to?

Comment: Yes. But that's what you want.

Comment: No, I don't want what is given in solution. I want the correct thing. Please explain why it will be less than equal to and not greater than equal to.

Comment: The correct thing is $f(x)\le 1+\pi/4$. In the above, since $f(x)\ge 1$ for $x\ge1$, you have $t^2+f^2(t)\ge t^2+1$, for $t\ge 1$. Taking reciprocals gives ${1\over t^2+f^2(t)}\le {1\over t^2+1}$.

Comment: Yes,you are absolutely right. This helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct your integral inequality, you have
$$ f(x) = 1+\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2+f^2(t)}\le 1+\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2+1}=1+F(x)-F(1)$$
for $x\ge 1$ where $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $x\mapsto\frac1{1+x^2}$. 
Note that "$\le$" comes into play because we divide by someting "$\ge$".
Now look up in your repository of standard integrals what $F$ might be. Hint: We may expect that $F(1)$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)$ somehow involve something with $\pi$.

Comment: $F$ is $\arctan$...and the limits should be $[1,\infty)$...is that right?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(1)=1$ and $f'(x)>0$, for all $x\ge 1$, then $f(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\ge 1$.
Thus
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}\le \frac{1}{1+x^2},
$$
for all $x\ge 1$, and finally,
\begin{align}
f(x)&=f(1)+\int_1^x f'(t)\,dt \le f(1)+\int_1^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=1+\arctan{t}\big|_1^x\\ &=1+\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{4}\le 1+\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}